# How to search for anything from an array of objects,?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter, jsx

How to search for anything from an array of objects,?

```
const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');

 let cars = [
    {
      "color": "purple",
      "type": "minivan",
      "registration": new Date('2017-01-03'),
      "capacity": 7
    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "type": "station wagon",
      "registration": new Date('2018-03-03'),
      "capacity": 5
    },
 
  ]


 return (
  <>

     <input type="text" onChange={(e) =>setSearchInput(e.target.value)}
    {
      cars?.filter(x => Object.values(x).includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())).map((d) =>{
         console.log(d) // nothing is consoled from here tu
        //show the data here  but nothing is showing here 
        
      })
    }

  </>
 )
```

No errors but the data are not showing whatsoever, what is wrong here?

Comment: ```Object.values(x).includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())``` will return Boolean value. thus map will not get executed

Comment: @SrushtiShah so what do I need to change to get what I want?

Comment: Please post your whole code so that I can help you

Comment: @TheDeadMan ... _"No errors but the data are not showing whatsoever, what is wrong here?"_ ... maybe a typo? ... `onChnage` should be `onChange`.

Comment: added setter and change onchange , but that is not the problem just typo while I was typing here on stack on my code no type if typo I could have got an error , but no errors , just data not showing up

Comment: Please try my answer posted below I have tried that

Comment: What actually is your input? What do users type into the input field? I tested your code, and it works fine.

Comment: @SrushtiShah search works but I need data to be displayed before searching , meaning user see all the data, and he can search anything he wants

Comment: for that you need to show the data in table and put a input box above table so that users cansearch and see the searched item. Am I understanding it right?

Comment: @SrushtiShah yes like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP for the search needs to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `cars` array where for every car `item` one needs to verify whether the `search` value is included in **[`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** of the item's [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

Also the OP needs to come up with the meaningful custom stringification of every item's value in order to assure a valid search result.

The provided approach implements a single filter function where everything from the above mentioned is included. The filter function is aware of its `this` context which is the to be searched value. The latter gets provided as the `filter` method's 2nd [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#parameters) parameter.

Thus a possible solution boils down to ... `cars.filter(doesItemContainBoundSearch, search)` ... which is proven with the next provided example code.

```js
function stringifySearchTarget(target) {
  return (target instanceof Date)
    ? target.toISOString()
    : String(target)
}
function doesItemContainBoundSearch(item) {
  const search = this.toLowerCase();
  return Object
    .values(item)
    .some(value =>
      stringifySearchTarget(value)
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(search)
    );
}

let cars = [{
  color: "purple",
  type: "minivan",
  registration: new Date('2017-01-03'),
  capacity: 7,
}, {
  color: "red",
  type: "station wagon",
  registration: new Date('2018-03-03'),
  capacity: 5,
}];

['o', 'a', 'ur', 'red', 'wagon', 'wagons']
  .forEach(search =>
    console.log([

      JSON.stringify(search),
      '=>',
      JSON.stringify(
      
        // the next line is everything the OP needs
        // in order to filter the `cars` array by
        // any item's value which matches the search.
        cars.filter(doesItemContainBoundSearch, search)
      ),
      
    ].join(' '))
  );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit** since the OP is in need of the correct react render code*

Filtering and rendering in **react** according to the OP's provided sandbox code would be ...

```
cars
  .filter(doesItemContainBoundSearch, searchInput)
  .map(car => (
    <tr>
      <td>{ car.color }</td>
      <td>{ car.type }</td>
      <td>{ car.capacity }</td>
    </tr>
  ))
```

or

```
cars
  .filter(doesItemContainBoundSearch, searchInput)
  .map(({ color, type, capacity }) => (
    <tr>
      <td>{ color }</td>
      <td>{ type }</td>
      <td>{ capacity }</td>
    </tr>
  ))
```

Comment: can you explain this ? can u used react example to and use ur function , I don't get it

Comment: @TheDeadMan ... code is thoroughly commented and explained.

Comment: I think I understand ur method but can u show its usage in jsx ?

Comment: @TheDeadMan ... Actually it is the OP's duty to provide a running stack snippet at first place.

Comment: here is a demo https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-joana-zpvi6e?file=/src/Demo.js

Comment: @TheDeadMan ... I don't have an account there, but i did fiddle around with it and the snippet which filters and renders the proper result there looks like provided with my last edit of the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the function filterCars below your cars array.

```
const filterCars = cars.filter(car => {
    if (!searchInput) {
      return cars
    }
    return car.color.includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) || car.type.includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
  })
```

Then your return statement,

```
return (
  <div>
   {
    filterCars.map(car => (
     <p>{car.color}</p>
     <p>{car.type}</p>
   )}
  </div>
)

Note: I excluded your input element because it's fine, and should work.
```

Comment: assume u have bunch of data not only color and type , ur method will not work well, thanks for ur suggestion though

Comment: you need to map that dynamically

Comment: @SrushtiShah what do u mean?

Comment: you need to do something like this ```Object.values(car).map((value) => (<p>{value}</p>))```

Answer (score -1):

```
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setSearchInput(e.target.value)} />
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>color</td>
            <td>type</td>
            <td>capacity</td>
          </tr>
          {searchInput ?
            <>
              {
                cars?.map((car) => (
                  Object.values(car).includes(searchInput?.toLowerCase()) &&
                  <tr>
                  <td>{car.color}</td>
                  <td>{car.type}</td>
                  <td>{car.capacity}</td>
                </tr>
                ))
              }
            </>
            :
            <>
              {cars?.map((car) => (
                <tr>
                  <td>{car.color}</td>
                  <td>{car.type}</td>
                  <td>{car.capacity}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </>
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </>
  )

}
```

Comment: react-dom.development.js:14887 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Comment: The error occures because you are trying to render "registration"'s value but react will not render date,object or array. It will be rendered only if the value is number or string

Comment: you can use string or numeber inside {} this brankets in return statement or you can call a function

Comment: can you show it ? I dont get it

Comment: I have edited the code you can try that now

Comment: <td>{car.color}</td> In this type of statement, You can not return objects or arryas, you can only return string or numbers, you are getting error becuase you are trying to return date object.

Comment: @SrushtiShah ... before mapping/rendering there must be always a `filter` task. It is missing throughout the above provided code.

Answer (score -1):

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
  let cars = [
    {
      "color": "purple",
      "type": "minivan",
      "registration": new Date('2017-01-03'),
      "capacity": 7
    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "type": "station wagon",
      "registration": new Date('2018-03-03'),
      "capacity": 5
    },
 
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={e=> setSearchInput(e.target.value)}/>
      {
      cars?.filter(x => Object.values(x).includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())).map((d) =>{
         console.log(d) // nothing is consoled from here tu
        return <span key={d.registration}>{d.color}</span>

        
      })
    }
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```